# Select HTML tags using attribute values and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<link rel="urlValue" href="http://www.something.com" />  

<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.other.com" />
```

How can I select the **href** value with rel="urlValue"? 
I've done this using JS

```
document.querySelectorAll('[rel="urlValue"]')[0].baseURI
```

But I need to get this using CSS selectors
Expected O/P : http://www.something.com

Comment: *"I need to get this using CSS selectors"*. `[rel="urlValue"]` *is* CSS selector. Clarify.

Comment: `[rel="urlValue]` itself is a css selector

Comment: If you want to get the `href` string then: `document.query selector("[rel=urlValue]").href;` but this is no different to what you've already used, which is a CSS selector (as already classified by others), so: what problem are you trying to solve, and how does your current implementation fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this with JS :

```js
var url = document.querySelector("[rel='urlValue']").getAttribute('href');
console.log(url);
```

```html
<link rel="urlValue" href="http://www.something.com" />  

<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.other.com" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something very similar in CSS using attribute selectors:

```
[rel="urlValue"] {
 // your styles here
}
```

or

```
[href="http://www.something.com"] {
 // your styles here
}
```

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 2):

Yes, CSS also have the same selector. You can select the element by using the attribute:

```
*[rel="urlValue"] {
  //your css
}
```

Comment: `*` is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Bear in mind he the OP didn't appear to be trying to style the element.

Comment: @dfsq yes that is not require, but for more understanding I have added the that.

Comment: @DavidThomas As per my understanding using the selector in css is used for defining the style as well as that's why I have added that.